# Go static library on Qt5: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, qt, go, qt5, static-libraries

I'm using a go build static library in Qt5, I add this in `.pro` file by:

```
LIBS += /Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxxxxx/framework/xxxx.a
```

And when I compiled, it gave me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SecCertificateCopyNormalizedIssuerContent", referenced from:
      _isRootCertificate in xxxx.a(000021.o)
  "_SecCertificateCopyNormalizedSubjectContent", referenced from:
      _isRootCertificate in xxxx.a(000021.o)
  "_SecCertificateCopyShortDescription", referenced from:
      _CopyPEMRoots in xxxx.a(000021.o)
  "_SecItemExport", referenced from:
      _CopyPEMRoots in xxxx.a(000021.o)
  "_SecPolicyCopyProperties", referenced from:
      _isSSLPolicy in xxxx.a(000021.o)
  "_SecTrustSettingsCopyCertificates", referenced from:
      _CopyPEMRoots in xxxx.a(000021.o)
  "_SecTrustSettingsCopyTrustSettings", referenced from:
      _sslTrustSettingsResult in xxxx.a(000021.o)
  "_kSecPolicyAppleSSL", referenced from:
      _isSSLPolicy in xxxx.a(000021.o)
  "_kSecPolicyOid", referenced from:
      _isSSLPolicy in xxxx.a(000021.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [xxxx.app/Contents/MacOS/xxxx] Error 1
09:27:27: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project xxxx (kit: Desktop Qt 5.13.1 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

But when I use `nm xxxx.a` I do see the symbols:

```
xxxx.a(000021.o):
                 U _CFArrayGetCount
                 U _CFArrayGetValueAtIndex
                 U _CFDataAppendBytes
                 U _CFDataCreateMutable
                 U _CFDataGetBytePtr
                 U _CFDataGetLength
                 U _CFDictionaryContainsKey
                 U _CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent
                 U _CFEqual
                 U _CFNumberGetValue
                 U _CFRelease
                 U _CFStringCreateWithCString
                 U _CFStringGetCString
                 U _CFStringGetLength
                 U _CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding
0000000000000000 T _CopyPEMRoots
                 U _SecCertificateCopyNormalizedIssuerContent
                 U _SecCertificateCopyNormalizedSubjectContent
                 U _SecCertificateCopyShortDescription
                 U _SecItemExport
                 U _SecPolicyCopyProperties
                 U _SecTrustSettingsCopyCertificates
                 U _SecTrustSettingsCopyTrustSettings
                 U ___stack_chk_fail
                 U ___stack_chk_guard
                 U ___stderrp
0000000000000890 T __cgo_0c91096c4ae5_Cfunc_CFDataGetBytePtr
00000000000008f0 T __cgo_0c91096c4ae5_Cfunc_CFDataGetLength
0000000000000950 T __cgo_0c91096c4ae5_Cfunc_CFRelease
0000000000000980 T __cgo_0c91096c4ae5_Cfunc_CopyPEMRoots
                 U __cgo_topofstack
                 U _fprintf
                 U _free
00000000000007e0 t _isRootCertificate
00000000000009f0 t _isSSLPolicy
                 U _kCFAllocatorDefault
                 U _kSecPolicyAppleSSL
                 U _kSecPolicyOid
                 U _malloc
0000000000000540 t _sslTrustSettingsResult
0000000000000c38 s l___const.CopyPEMRoots.domains
```

What's wrong with it? How to solve this problem?
I have tried to `clean` and run `qmake`. However it didn't work.
I also tried to recompile the static library, Unfortunately, it is also not working.

Comment: The letter `U` means that the object file *refers to* the symbol without defining it. (Uppercase indicates exported symbols, T means Text, and U means Undefined.) Figure out which library actually *defines* these symbols and be sure to link against it.

Comment: I figure out it's ``crypto/x509`` this package. But I can't make it export. I'm using ``GOBUILD=CGO_ENABLED=0  \go build -buildmode=c-archive`` to build static library

Comment: Go's symbols are not callable from C++ in general. You must provide wrappers.

Comment: I find out the issue. These symbols are all in Apple's ``Security`` framework. After I add it in my ``.pro`` file. Errors disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the symbols mentioned above were in Apple's `Security` framework.
   Look at this link for more detail: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1400261-sectrustsettingscopytrustsetting?language=objc).
I Solved it by add below code fragment in my `.pro` file.

```
macx {
    LIBS += -framework Security
}
```

Clean all, run qmake and run it. The errors should be disappear by now.